# Hibernate List mapping idx invalid identifier

Tags: hibernate, orm, mapping

I'm trying to replace bag mapping with list to avoid multiple bag fetching problem. I checked all the information on Google and find this:

```
<list name="whatEver">
    <key column="whatEver_fk"/>
    <index column="idx"/>
    <one-to-many class="WhatEver"/>
</list>
```

But it does not work for me, it always says ."idx" invalid identifier. I followed exactly what's written in document and it also seems a lot ppls can make it work.
I also tried to configure bi-directional or uni directional(someone claimed the uni directional will work), neither works.

Comment: Did you add a column in your actual Database called idx ?

Comment: No, I think that's the problem. But someone said it's automatically maintained by Hibernate, it seems this is not the case.

Comment: just check the presence of this column in your DB

Comment: I think the statement from internet: "idx is maintained automatically by Hibernate" is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the statement from internet: "idx is maintained automatically by Hibernate" is false. We must have this one present and mapped with an actual database column.